# Why am i getting this error when running a python executable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, sudoku

ok so this are the libraries im using in a python program that solves a sudoku.

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "(?s).*MATPLOTLIBDATA.*", category=UserWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

import cv2
import os
os.environ['OPENCV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS']=str(2**64)
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pytesseract
from imutils import contours
from selenium import webdriver
```

when i run this code in pycharm the program works well, however when i use the executable of the project i get this error, i dont know why.

```
C:\Users\carme\PycharmProjects\SudokuSolver\venv\Scripts\dist\main>main.exe
c:\users\carme\pycharmprojects\sudokusolver\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Matplotlib installs where the data is not in the mpl-data subdirectory of the package are deprecated since 3.2 and support for them will be removed two minor releases later.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\carme\pycharmprojects\sudokusolver\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 905, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 480, in _get_data_path
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 239, in wrapper
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 534, in get_data_path
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 239, in wrapper
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 563, in _get_data_path
NameError: name 'defaultParams' is not defined
[19212] Failed to execute script main
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out after trial and error that pyinstaller has a conflict with the latest version of matplotlib. In order to produce an executable of your script with pyinstaller you should downgrade matplotlib to 3.2.2 version. I have also found some problems with the latest (1.19.4) version of numpy which went away when I downgraded numpy to 1.19.3.

You can check my repository https://github.com/matiasleoni/COVID19_plotter where I created a simple script to plot COVID19 global data using matplotlib package. After many failed attempts I was also able to create an executable version of it as I described above (see also the README.md of that repository).